# Can I write a script / bot to forward text messages from a specific SMS account (a bank) to another phone number? And at a high level, how?

Tags: sms

I have 2FA turned on at my bank. I share this account with my partner, and anytime either of us try to logon, *I* get a code texted to me from my bank, but he doesn't (product is crap).

I want to write a script / bot that will allow me to automatically forward the text message from my bank to my partner, always, so I am not a bottleneck to him logging on.

Can someone please help inform / guide me on how I can solve this with technology? Thanks so much!

I've tried contacting the bank and they told me a bunch of legal reasons as to why there can only be one login per account and so we'll just need to deal.